# Are AWS root storage ephemeral?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is AWS root storage ephemeral? The documents say they are ephemeral. But, I still can find my files after stopping the instance for some time and reboot it, I can still view my files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created your instance, I assume you chose the EBS backed instance. This means that the root device volume is actually an EBS volume, so when the instance restarts, you still have all of your data. If you were to choose the instance-store backed instance, then you would lose your data when restarting.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by root storage?

Instance Stores are ephemeral. EBS volumes are not.

When launching an instance, if you've selected Instance Store as the root volume, a restart will still retain the data. But a stop and start will delete all data.

If you've selected an EBS volume, the data will be retained.

Comment: Hi Yeshodhan Kulkarni, thanks for the response. root storage in specific means that it is instance storage rather than EBS volumes which come with AMI. As specified earlier, I have stopped the instance for a period of 5 minutes and started it again. But, I can still view my files that I have created before on Redhat AMI.

Comment: If you are confident about the issue, try asking AWS support for help. I've personally not observed any such issue with Instance Stores on AWS.